# Ionic/Angular2 input regex pattern is broken

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

After some updates in my project a input pattern doesn't work anymore. Looks like after update to Ionic 2.1.18 input pattern seems to be broken:
This part worked for me before but now **Password.valid** is always false:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password*</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" required [(ngModel)]="regModel.Password" name="Password"
               #Password="ngModel" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d*\w]{5,}$"
               (change)="checkPassword()"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item no-border no-lines no-margin *ngIf="!Password.valid && Password.dirty" color="danger">
    <small>Five characters minimum,</small>
    <br>
    <small> at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase and 1 number {{Password.valid}} {{Password.dirty}}
    </small>
  </ion-item>
```

**Update**

Funny thing, some of simple regular expressions work fine, but another - don't, e.g. [a-zA-Z ]* - works fine, \d{5} - don't

Comment: Try `[pattern]` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992630/input-validation-with-pattern-angularjs-2

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone else will happen to encounter problem with Ionic `pattern`, here is an working example of a password that:

- contain at least one number
- at least one special character
- at least one lowercase character
- at least one uppercase character

inside `.ts` file:

```
export class SignUpPage {
  public PASSWORD_REGEX = `.*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\\$%\\^&\\*]).*`

 // ...
}
```

inside `HTML`:

```
 <ion-input [(ngModel)]="signUpData.password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            #password="ngModel"
            [minlength]="10"
            [pattern]="PASSWORD_REGEX"
            required>
 </ion-input>
```

Note: I've omitted password length check in regex and put inside `[minlength]` property, so the length can be easily controlled without digging into regex, however, if you want it to be implemented with regex way, use this one:
`.*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{10,})` - here user should provide at least 10 characters long password.

Comment: Thanks! I've spent some time trying to figure out what pattern works for strong password validation in Ionic. This one actually does!